# Repositioning step in impress.js

Tags: javascript, impress.js

I am looking for a way to reposition a step (or 'slide') in impress.js. Generally, steps center on a page and when you resize your browser, they resize (and recenter) accordingly (at least for most screen sizes). My aim is to create an offset, so that a 'slide' is moved horizontally to the right.

Does anyoneone have an idea how impress.js can be modified accordingly?

Thank you in advance for your ideas,

Arjan

Comment: without a fiddle nobody can help you

Answer (score 0):

The data-x and data-y properties are used to position your slides. So if you want slide 2 500 pixels to the right, you'd so something like this:

```
<div id="slideTwo" class="step" data-x="500" data-y="0">
 Slide content here
</div>
```